# Concatenate dataframes Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes. Their shapes are (2656, 246), (2656, 2412) and (2656, 7025). I want to merge dataframes as above:

[image]

So It will result a (2656, 9683) Dataframe. Thanks for any help.

Typo on image: on Dataframe 3, it will 7025, not 5668.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the rows are in same order that you wish to merge all of the dataframes, you can use the concat command specificying axis=1.

`new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`

If the row index for each of the data frames are different and you want to merge them in the current order, you can also apply ignore_index:

`new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)`

For details on the merge, join & concatenation operations, please refer to the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).